# using infinite loop in a button click event

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

Is there any known problem if I use an infinite for loop within a button click event? Actually, first I set up the program by taking settings from the GUI. Then when I click start button, I want a function to be called continuously. That function is not part of the GUI. it's a function from the remaining part of the program.

Comment: I really don't undarstend your question, without see short example that shows us what you are tried

Comment: @mKorbel: I think the question is completely clear!  I'm not sure that an example is necessary here.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth maybe then let's wait for OP's ... :-), @Paŭlo Ebermann has my favorite answer +1

Comment: @aps, It's basic Swing knowledge that long-running tasks (e.g. an infinite loop) should never occur on the `EDT`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your GUI will stop responding.

You should fire off a worker thread to do the computation instead.  Recommended reading:

- [*Threads and Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)
- [*Using a Swing worker thread*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but in a separate thread, otherwise you'll block the UI thread and the application will get stuck and force closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is: the GUI will completely be frozen. You have to execute long-running tasks in a background thread. This is usually done using a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Have a look at the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to learn how to use them.

Comment: +1, if you link to javadocs, and maybe provide an example. :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for helping me in my fight against my own lazyness :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your event handler (ActionListener, here) is called in the AWT event dispatch thread (EDT).

This thread is the same thread that handles all the user interaction, as well as repainting your application. If you don't return soon from the action listener, your application will seem frozen.

Don't do that, use a new thread instead. (For GUI updating, call back into the EDT using EventQueue.invokeLater (or SwingUtilities.invokeLater, this is the same).)